# Does every sequence of group epimorphisms (between finitely generated groups) contain a stable subsequence?

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, group-theory, geometric-group-theory

I have a question that is related to the topic of limit groups:

Let $G$ and $H$ be finitely generated groups and let $(\varphi_n: G \to H)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of group epimorphisms. Does there exist a stable subsequence of  $(\varphi_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$?

This is the definition of "stable sequence":

Let G be a group and $(\varphi_n) _{n \in \mathbb{N}}⊂ Hom(G, H)$. The sequence  $(\varphi_n) _{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is stable if
for any $g ∈ G$ either $\varphi_n(g) = 1$ for almost all $n$ or $\varphi_n(g)\neq 1$ for almost all $n$.

I conjecture that the answer to the question is positive, because the statement of the question is used on page 27 of the following article (in the article we have a sequence of epimorphisms $g_n: F_l \to L$ to which the statement of my question is applied to):

https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.10278.pdf

Edit: In the above article we have the situation that G is a free group of rank at least two and H is a non-abelian limit group. So it would be sufficient if somebody can answer my question for this situation. Of course you can still say something to the general situation.

Edit: "Almost all" means that the statement ist true for all natural numbers with possibly a finite number of exceptions.

Comment: Please edit your post to: 1) specify the domain and codomain of $\varphi_n$, 2) type the definition of "stable sequence" instead of relying on a link, 3) include some attempts. [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: What do you mean? The definition of "stable sequence" requires that *for every* $g \in G$ either [...]. Of course this is true then *for every $g \in S$* because $S$ is a subset of $G$. But maybe you mean something else. Why does this imply that the answer is "yes"?

Comment: Nevermind, these conditions are not equivalent.

Comment: @TheMathematician the linked arxiv paper doesn't talk about stable sequences. Or at least I don't see how this is related. Can you elaborate?

Comment: No, they are not equivalent, sure.

Comment: Yes, I can elaborate. In the article (on page 27) we have the following text: " As we did in
proving theorem 2.2, with each generating set $S_n$ we can associate an
epimorphism: $g_n: F_l → L$.
From the sequence of epimorphisms ${g_n}$ we can pass to a subsequence that converges into a limit group $L_1$ with a generating set
$U$." I think here the statement of my question is used. The relation to my question is that there exists a subsequence of the sequence of epimorphisms ${g_n}$ that converges into a Limit group $L_1$. And *by definition* of a limit group you need a stable sequence.

Comment: I edited my question to refer to the situation in the article.

Comment: Are the maps in the sequence related to one another somehow? In particular, is $\operatorname{im}(\varphi_n)\geq\operatorname{im}(\varphi_{n+1})$, or can you find a subsequence with this property? Descending chains of bounded-rank subgroups of free groups are pretty stable (see the exercises on pp118-119 of Magnus, Karrass and Solitar), so this situation can likely be lifted the limit group setting.

Comment: Unfortunately I dont have access to the book you refer to. No, a priori they are not related to each other. But the inclusion $im(\varphi_n) \supset im(\varphi_{n+1})$ is trivially fullfilled because the $\varphi_n$ are epimorphisms. But in the situation of the $g_n$ in the article we have more  because the $g_n$ are defined using uniformly bounded generating sets of $L$. But it is not possible to write down all the details of the situation of the article. You can find them on page 27 at the top.

Comment: I do think this question (and most of your other questions on this paper!) would be better suited to MathOverflow. Asking there is more likely to get you an answer than adding a bounty here.

Comment: (Oh, one further thing - your definition of "stable" is incomplete, because you have not defined "almost all". Is it just the standard "$\lim_{n\to\infty}(\#\text{words with this property of length }\leq n)/(\#\text{words of length }\leq n)$"?)

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I thought that MathStackexchange would be in some sense the same as MathOverflow but now I know the difference.  "Almost all" means that the statement ist true for all natural numbers with possibly a finite number of exceptions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is yes by a standard diagonal argument.$\def\phi{\varphi}$ We need only assume $G$ is countable (which is weaker than assuming it is finitely generated). Let $G = \{g_1, g_2, g_3, \dots\}$ be a countable group and let $(\varphi_n : G \to H)_{n \in \mathbf N}$ be a sequence of homomorphisms. There is a subsequence $(\varphi^{1}_n)$ of $(\varphi_n)$ such that $\varphi^1_n(g_1)$ is identically $1$ or identically $\ne 1$. There is a further subsequence $(\varphi^2_n)$ of $(\varphi^1_n)$ such that $\varphi^2_n(g_2)$ is identically $1$ or identically $\ne 1$. Continue, definining an infinite sequence of subsequences $(\phi^1_n), (\phi^2_n), (\phi^3_n), \dots$ such that, for all $i$, $(\phi^i_n)_n$ is a subequence of $(\phi^{i-1}_n)_n$ such that $\phi^i_n(g_i)$ is identically $1$ or identically $\ne 1$. Finally consider diagonal subsequence $\psi_n = \phi^n_n$ and observe that $\psi_n(g_i)$ is identically $1$ or identically $\ne 1$ for $n \ge i$.

This argument is perfectly analogous to the proof that $\{0,1\}^{\mathbf N}$ is compact. Actually the claim reduces to that fact. Define $f_n : \mathbf N \to \{0,1\}$ by $f_n(i) = 0 \iff \varphi_n(g_i) = 1$. Since $\{0,1\}^\mathbf N$ is compact (and metrizable), $(f_n)$ has a convergent subsequence, and if you unpack the definitions that is precisely what you want.